# Iteratively change column classes in a set range

Tags: r

I am working with a modest survey dataset (190 x 2162). The platform we are using exports to csv, but when imported every column is a factor. I could assign each column a class on import, but a recent change of hats at work has put many more surveys in my future. So, out of respect for my future self's sanity, I am looking to build a small library of functions to convert ranges of columns as needed.

Goals of the initial function:

- Convert from factor to numeric
- Take column names as input, rather than numbers

The core of the function appears to work fine:

```
startNum <- match("Q7_1", names(rawNum))
endNum <- match("Q7_19", names(rawNum))

for(i in c(startNum:endNum)){
  rawNum[,i] <- as.character(rawNum[,i])
  rawNum[,i] <- as.numeric(rawNum[,i])
}
```

However, when I attempt to wrap this in a function, it falls apart. I believe the issue is in passing the *_col_name arguments into the function, but I can't seem to find where it is going wrong.

```
facToNum <- function(frame_name, start_col_name, end_col_name){

    startNum <- match(start_col_name, names(frame_name))
    endNum <- match(end_col_name, names(frame_name))

    for(i in c(startNum:endNum)){
    frame_name[,i] <- as.character(frame_name[,i])
    frame_name[,i] <- as.numeric(frame_name[,i])
  }
}
```

What am I missing here? I'm sure it's something obvious, but I've had to soldier on with my partial solution, and it rankles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any obvious mistakes in your function except that you need to `return` the changed dataframe at the end of the function.

```
facToNum <- function(frame_name, start_col_name, end_col_name){
  
  startNum <- match(start_col_name, names(frame_name))
  endNum <- match(end_col_name, names(frame_name))
  
  for(i in c(startNum:endNum)){
    frame_name[,i] <- as.character(frame_name[,i])
    frame_name[,i] <- as.numeric(frame_name[,i])
  }
  return(frame_name)
}
```

You can also simplify your approach using `dplyr` library.

```
library(dplyr)

facToNum <- function(frame_name, start_col_name, end_col_name){
  frame_name %>%
    mutate(across(start_col_name:end_col_name, ~as.numeric(as.character(.x))))
}

df <- data.frame(a = factor(rnorm(5)), b = factor(runif(5)), c = 1:5)
str(df)

#data.frame':   5 obs. of  3 variables:
# $ a: Factor w/ 5 levels "-1.64324479436782",..: 3 1 5 4 2
# $ b: Factor w/ 5 levels "0.11049344507046",..: 1 4 3 2 5
# $ c: int  1 2 3 4 5

result <- facToNum(df, "a", "b")
str(result)

#'data.frame':  5 obs. of  3 variables:
# $ a: num  -0.11733 -1.64324 1.26266 0.00823 -0.9531
# $ b: num  0.11 0.614 0.545 0.228 0.902
# $ c: int  1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: Really appreciate this, the dplyr simplification especially. I've only started to scratch the surface of dplyr and the associated libraries, so this is very much appreciated.

I'm not sure I fully understand why ~as.numeric(as.character(.x)) works - are there suggestions for resources on understanding the ~ and .x portions? I'm self-taught and find ~ and . particularly difficult to get my head around.

Comment: That is similar to anonymous function. I do have a video explaining it https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ynaHKNdAAwk